# Using convolution to impose differentiablilty.

Tags: derivatives, convolution

If I had a function $g$ that was not differentiable at a known point, is it possible to convolute it with say a $C^{\infty}$ function $f$, resulting in a differentiable function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you might mean "convolve" rather than convolute. The answer is generally "yes," but to prove differentiability, you'll need to be able to differentiate through an integral, basically using Leibnitz's theorem; there may be some condition on the integrand. If your function $g$ is continuous and bounded, that should be sufficient (but not necessary).

Comment: @John, Damn, I went to write convolve, then changed my mind, my function of interest (for convolving) would be the signed distance function, defined on the interior of a uniformly convex domain.

Comment: I believe that what you're looking for is the [mollifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier).

Comment: I that case, convolving against some nice compactly supported $C^\infty$ "bump function" would almost certainly result in a differentiable function. The "mollifier" reference above is a good place to start looking for details,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in comments: this works quite well. We only need $g$ to be locally integrable. Let $f$ be $C^\infty$ smooth and compactly supported; normalize by $\int f=1$. Then

- $f*g$ is $C^\infty $ smooth, with derivatives given by $D^k(f*g) = (D^kf)*g$;
- if $f$ is rescaled as $\lambda^{-d}f(x/\lambda)$, where $d$ is the dimension of ambient space, then the convolutions converge to $g$ as $\lambda\to 0$. The convergence holds a.e., and also in  $L^p$ norm provided $g\in L^p$.

The above facts are found in any decent book on real analysis; e.g., *Real Analysis* by Folland.